# I am using the dev c++ and i am getting the error ( C++98 'array' must be initialized by constructor)

Tags: c++

I am using the Dev c++ application for writing the code in C/C++. When I used the Veter iterator. For, Iterating the array value. Then I am getting this one error.
"[Error] in C++98 'array' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'. Also, I am using Window 10.

Code :-

```
vector<int> array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: vector<int> array{1,2,3,4,5};

Comment: [Warning]:- extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: also same error will come. By using this one vector<int> array{1,2,3,4,5};

Comment: are you not able to use c++11?

Comment: how to add c++11. I will just install and start write the code

Comment: You need to pass `-std=c++11` as an argument to the compiler. See your IDE's documentation for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the so called `initializer_list` (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957393/what-does-initializer-list-do) if you do not know what they are) which is a way of costructing objects introduced by `c++11`.

Hence you need to tell your compiler that you want to use  `c++11` by passing the argument `-std=c++11` to the compiler itself.

[Take a look at this question to see how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613295/how-can-i-compile-c11-code-with-orwell-dev-c)

Answer (score 2):

You must change the compiler option to C++11. There is a similar question here: [How to change mode from c++98 mode in Dev-C++ to a mode that supports C++0x (range based for)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran)